# Dashboard to show historical metrics produced by cron jobs?

Tags: graphs, statistics, dashboard

I would like to have a dashboard (I'm thinking on something as a static web page with dynamic data) to display some metrics that I generate with cronjobs...

For example, I count the files on a folder I would like to cleanup then I can see on the dashboard how that project is progressing... Is there any simple way to have something like that?

The only requirement is that it needs to be self-hosted and I would prefer free-software.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [sargraph](https://github.com/sargraph/sargraph.github.io) and tune your logs in format, accepted by this software.

I know the idea of this software is different but is is quite flexible.